# Adding EXIF data to Images

Tags: python, exif

I want to add modify exif data in an image by modifying the ImageDescription tag. I use the library from the following:

```
https://github.com/bennoleslie/pexif
```

I am able to modify the ImageDescription tag and read the modified tag after writing it to another image file. But now when i upload the image to imgur and instagram and download the image again, and read the exif data, the modified ImageDescription tag is not there anymore in the exif data. To read the exif data, i use tools like exiftool and identify -v, but none them display the modified ImageDescription. I also used the above pxeif library to read the tag name ImageDescription and its not there. Any suggestions for why this is happening?

Below is the code i used using the pexif library and the image is a .jpg:

```
img = pexif.JpegFile.fromFile(path_to_images + image)
image_id = image.split('.')[0]
img.exif.primary.ImageDescription =  image_id
img.writeFile(path_to_encoded_images + image_id + "_encoded.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This likely isn't the fault of your code or the library.  Many image hosting services deliberately strip exif data.  So, even if the data is well formed, don't count on it surviving imgur or instagram (or others for that matter).

See http://imgur.userecho.com/topic/42809-where-is-the-exif-data/ and http://www.embeddedmetadata.org/social-media-test-results.php

As to why they do this, there are probably various answers.  Probably one big one is that less savvy users won't unwittingly post their gps coordinates all over the place via geo tagging.